# How can I revert 'fancy lambdas' after an edit

Tags: emacs, clojure, elisp

When editing clojure code in emacs, it's common to tweak font-lock to insert 'fancy' characters for lambdas, sets, anon functions.

This is achieved with some variant of the following (seen in clojure-mode, emacs-live etc.)

```
(dolist (mode '(clojure-mode clojurescript-mode nrepl-interaction-mode))
  (eval-after-load mode
    (font-lock-add-keywords
     mode '(("(\\(fn\\)[\[[:space:]]"  ; anon funcs 1
             (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                       (match-end 1) "λ")
                   nil)))
        ("\\(#\\)("                ; anon funcs 2
         (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                   (match-end 1) "ƒ")
                   nil)))
        ("\\(#\\){"                 ; sets
         (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                   (match-end 1) "∈")
                   nil)))))))
```

This works great until you make an edit around the fancy character. You can leave hanging characters as per the following screenshot...
[image]

How can I get emacs to revert back to the 'real' characters when I've made an edit. The `nil`(s) in the code above could be a modification function that (presumably) does this and there is a `(decompose-region)` that seems to fit the bill. How should it be invoked, passing it as symbol doesn't work.

e.g. I've tried this:

```
(dolist (mode '(clojure-mode clojurescript-mode nrepl-interaction-mode))
  (eval-after-load mode
    (font-lock-add-keywords
     mode '(("(\\(fn\\)[\[[:space:]]"  ; anon funcs 1
             (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                       (match-end 1) "λ")
                       'decompose-region)))
            ("\\(#\\)("                ; anon funcs 2
             (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                       (match-end 1) "ƒ")
                       'decompose-region)))
            ("\\(#\\){"                 ; sets
             (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                       (match-end 1) "∈")
                       'decompose-region)))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add `(set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-extra-managed-props) '(composition))`.